# error : Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand the problem, if I know anyone new in this world, please help me.
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: What don't you understand? The only object that you are allowed to render directly in JSX is *array*.

Comment: You are trying to render an error object as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Inside React Componenets you can't render objects directly

for exmaple:

```
const component=()=>{
    const user={
      fname:"John",
      lname:"Wick"
    }
    return (
      <div> the current user is {user} </div>
    )

}
```

In this code above, you will get an error of object is not a valid react child.

Solution: Always render the properties of the objects or use map() if you have an array of objects.

```
const component=()=>{
    const user={
      fname:"John",
      lname:"Wick"
    }
    return (
      <div> the current user is {user.fname} {user.lname} </div>
    )

}
```

Now, since you're rendering the properties and not the object, you'll have no error§

Comment: Or, if you are a lazy ____ like me, `<div> the current user is {JSON.stringify(user)} </div>` should be somewhat readable too. At the bare minimum, it won't throw the original error. :-)